# WSO2 Data Service - Is there any mechanism to record the IP from who called a operation?

Tags: logging, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

We need to record ip, date time and user that did any operation in our system to log. Is there one easy/fast way to do it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom logging module according to your need and deploy that in wso2dss server. Here is a [reference](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/search/label/log4j) on how to write your custom logging module. Basically, you van pick the above mentioned information at axis2 level and do logging.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I'll try insert the logs in the database.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use our MT-Logging architecture with BAM where we store the above information such as record ip, date time and user. Please refer [1]  on configuring Distributed MT-Logging  with WSO2 BAM.

[1] - http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-configure-mt-logging-with-wso2.html